# AttributeError: 'Board' object has no attribute 'marked_sqr'

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.squares = np.zeros( (ROWS, COLS) )
        self.empty_sqrs = self.squares #Creates a list of empty squares
        self.marked_sqrs = 0 # the amount of squares that have been played

    def final_state(self):...

    def mark_sqr(self, row, col, player):... #dropping the piece

    def empty_sqr(self, row, col):
        return self.squares[row][col] == 0

    def is_valid_location(self, col):
        return self.squares[ROWS - 1][col] == 0
```

This class is getting called by my Game class:

```
class Game:
def __init__(self):
    self.board = Board()
    self.ai = AI()
    self.player = 1 # what player starts
    self.gamemode = 'ai' #ai or pvp
    self.running = True
    self.draw_housing()

def make_move(self, row, col):
    self.board.marked_sqr(row, col, self.player)
    self.draw_board()
    self.next_turn()
```

There is more code in both my game and board classes but I do not think they are relevant to this problem.

I initialize a board variable with `game = game()` and `board = game.board`. But the problem arises when I try and call

```
if board.is_valid_location(col) and game.running:
                row = board.get_next_open_row(col)
                game.make_move(row,col)
```

I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/tyler/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/Connect_4_AI/Connect4_Better.py", line 236, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/tyler/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/Connect_4_AI/Connect4_Better.py", line 200, in main
    game.make_move(row,col)
  File "c:/Users/tyler/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/Connect_4_AI/Connect4_Better.py", line 120, in make_move   
    self.board.marked_sqr(row, col, self.player)
AttributeError: 'Board' object has no attribute 'marked_sqr'
```

I have another A.I for Tic Tac Toe that uses something very similar but does not have this problem.

Comment: Typo "marked_sqr" -> "mark_sqr"

Comment: The attribute is actually named `marked_sqrs` but you're trying to use `marked_sqr`.